# Problems with caching using NSURLConnection and querying HTTP Headers

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to write a crude app to loop round querying some of the HTTP Header fields that come back from my server in order to find out which servers are responding OK. My servers respond with a header like this:
server = server1 (or server2, server 3 etc).

Unfortunately when I do this I get the same server name back time and time again from the app unless I stop it and run it again at which point I get a different server back. How can I stop this happening? I need the app to treat each connection as if it is brand new, but it seems to cache something and appear to come from the same place, so my load balancer returns the same server name.

I can replicate similar behaviour(expected) in Safari by going to my URL repeatedly without shutting down Safari - it gets the same server each time, but if I shut down Safari then go back into it I get a new server.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 999; i++) {
    request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:10];

    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: &response error: nil];
    if ([response respondsToSelector:@selector(allHeaderFields)]) {
        dictionary = [response allHeaderFields];
        fullHeaderString = [dictionary description];
    }
}
```

How can I make this connection be treated like a new one every time?

Cheers,
Tom

Answer (score 1):

You can make sure the content is freshly loaded each time in at least 2 ways:

1. Add the "pragma: no-cache" header
   to your http response. This should
   make the http client not cache the
   response.
2. Add a random query
   parameter to the request like: url =
   "http://myhost.com/controller/blabla?rand=" + Math.random(...). This would make the url unique each time but the
   server would probably not care about
   the parameter so it would still be
   safe.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. 

No luck unfortunately - adding the query parameter to the URL hasn't made any difference (same effect in Safari as well), and I can't edit the HTTP responses (I certainly can't on the server anyway). That did give me the idea to try hitting the site over https instead of http to reduce the chance of it caching - still no luck unfortunately.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that it is cached? Try it with firefox and see if firebug reports the site as cached. Perhaps your load balancer is using the same server every time?

Comment: I'm not sure it is cached - if I do the same in Firefox or Safari I get the same server every time. I'm not sure exactly how the load balancer achieves this, but it takes quitting the browser (not just shutting the tab) to get a new server. This is the expected behaviour for the site. What I need to do is work out how to achieve the same sort of result as quitting the browser and starting again from inside my iPhone app. If I do quit the iPhone app and load it again I get a new server, same as a browser. But I want to repeatedly hit different servers from within my app.

Comment: Ok, perhaps you could read the load balancer documentation to see how it does this? Another idea is to clear all the cookies as the load balancer might use cookies.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same problem, but I just figured it out after reading your post, so I thought i'd share what I learned.

In `connection:didReceiveData:` I was appending the incoming bytes to an NSData object in the delegate. However, I was not clearing out that buffer in between requests: i was merely appending data to the end of it. My parsing algorithm simply looked for the first instance of the xml response and passed it back, which means it was passing back the OLD data.

In conclusion, the system wasn't doing any caching; I was.

The solution: before you make each call clear out your data:

```
[myData setData:[NSData data]];
```

Hope that this works for you. I know it's saving a huge headache on my end.

Comment: `[NSData new]` leaks. Use `[NSData data]` for a balanced version, or `[[NSData new] autorelease]` if you *must* use `+new` (which is a semi-deprecated method name, by the by.)

Comment: Oh i thought that `new` was the equivalent to `[[[NSData alloc] init] autorelease]`. Is that not the case?

Comment: No, it's equivalent to `[[NSData alloc] init]`. The equivalent to `[[[NSData alloc] init] autorelease]` is `[NSData data]`.